# Clustering classifier and clustering policy

Tags: cluster-analysis, mahout, k-means

I was going through the K-means algorithm in mahout and when debugging, I noticed that when creating the first clusters it does this following code:

```
ClusteringPolicy policy = new KMeansClusteringPolicy(convergenceDelta);
ClusterClassifier prior = new ClusterClassifier(clusters, policy);
prior.writeToSeqFiles(priorClustersPath);
```

I was reading the description of these classes and it was not clear for me...

I was wondering what is the meaning of these cluster classifier and policy?
is it related with hierarchical clustering, centroid based clustering, distribution based
clustering etc?

Because I do not know what is the benefit or the reason of using this cluster classifier and policy when using K-means mahout implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation shares code with other variants of k-means and similar algorithms such as Canopy pre-clustering and GMM.

These classes encode only the difference between these algorithms.

Mahout is not a good place to study the k-means algorithm, the implementation is quite a mess. It's also slow. As in really really slow. Most of the time, a single CPU implementation will outright beat Mahout on anything that fits into memory. Maybe even on disk of a single machine. Because of all the map-reduce overhead.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Anony-Mousse, now I see the reason of this policy.
I will be reading other K-means implementations such as R and Weka then.
Could you explain more about this map-reduce overhead please?

Comment: By the way, in a previous post you recommended me ELKI or scipy implementations for a single CPU. 
But do you know some some other parallel k-means implementations?
Thanks

Comment: I'm not aware of one. I don't think k-means is *interesting* enough for that. See: it's a statistical method. On larger data, the result will still be the same, except for a tiny bit of precision. **Big data k-means is totally useless.**